# How to Fix Overly Refractive Window?

Tags: world, hdri

I just recently got back into doing 3D work after being out of it for over a decade and jumped back into Blender.

The problem I'm having is with some strange scaling with an HDRI image I have.  In the viewport, in camera view, it almost exactly how i want it:

[image]

But this is how it appears when rendered, extremely zoomed in:

[image]

I've tried using a Mapping node to get it to look correct, but all I end up getting is an extremely distorted image.

All my settings for the Environment Texture in the screenshots are set to defaults.

Thanks.

edit:

So it appears that the problem is with my window and not with the background image.

When I deleted the window everything appears just as it does in the viewport screenhot.  It appears that the window pane is refracting too much.  Is there a way to fix this?  The glass is not a single-face (it has thickness) and it is the same glass I'm using for the table top, which looks fine.  Here is my node setup:

[image]

Comment: You probably have only 1 plane as your glass object, correct? This means computationally the rays are entering inside the glass, but never coming out so it's infinitely thick. Just extrude the plane into a think sheet and you have physically correct glass. Alternatively you could just omit the entire glass plane there, it's probably not going to reflect anything against the bright exterior and it's only making your scene computationally heavier with refraction in every ray of light..

Comment: Actually it does have a thickness.  I would have liked glass there to reflect the walls, but I guess that's not a huge issue.  Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: When it has thickness, make sure all normals are facing outward.

Comment: It turns out the face on the inside of my glass pane had been deleted!  Well, I feel like an idiot!  Thanks for your help, everyone.

Comment: Glass only displays reflections from objects that are brighter than the what's on the other side of the glass which is why I doubt you'd have any reflections on the glass. But that's only if you're doing physically accurate / realistic render where you light the scene using emissive HDR environment.